# Show/hide Mahapps Flyout control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

How can I show/hide **MahApps Flyout** control? Now I have:

```
<controls:FlyoutsControl>
    <controls:Flyout Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200" IsOpen="True">
        <TextBlock FontSize="24">Hello World</TextBlock>
    </controls:Flyout>
</controls:FlyoutsControl>
```

And it's open, but when I click the button with arrow I can't show it again.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can simply use something like this:

```
yourMahAppFlyout.IsOpen = true;
```

Also you can bind the Flyout visibility to a `WindowCommand` (`LeftWindowCommand`/`RightWindowCommand`) so whenever you close the Flyout you can reopen using a `ToggleButton` (for example) from the top of the window.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout"/>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>

<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <ToggleButton Content="Layers" 
        IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=yourMahAppFlyout, Path=IsOpen}" Cursor="Hand"/>               
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```